# DBeaver Can't access non-default database

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I'm using DBeaver 3.8.0 and trying to setup general connection to my local PostgreSQL database.

To view all the databases i have, I check the "Show non-default databases" checkbox. And when I try to access Schemas of one of my databases - I'm getting the error

`org.jkiss.dbeaver.DBException: Can't access non-default database`

[image: Connection settings]
[image: Access error]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DBeaver can only see default PostgreSQL database in connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235029/dbeaver-can-only-see-default-postgresql-database-in-connection)

Answer (score 90, accepted):

Try to set your database active which you choose to open the schema:

[image: picture]

Comment: I think it would be nice to have a configuration or setting where one can select "Set Active on click" OR "Set Active on double-click". This would be a nice to-have - similar to what happens in HeidiSQL

Comment: @CodeBurner yeah. This is obnoxious. It's quite an obvious oversight.

Comment: @CodeBurner Newer versions have this [checkbox in the connection settings](https://github.com/dbeaver/dbeaver/issues/2892#issuecomment-362343541).

Answer (score 20):

1. Right-click on the Db Connection in the database navigator (right-click on PostgreSQL)
2. Click on edit connection

[image]

3. Select PostgreSQL tab
4. Select Show all databases

[image]

5. Click ok to save

Note: I am using DBeaver Enterprise 7.0.0

Comment: this is works for me

Answer (score 1):

For more recent versions of DBeaver, you can improve this confusing default behavior.

You need to change an "Editors" setting.  There are several ways to get to the setting, an easy way is:

> [Postgres - #name#] right-click > Properties

Under Editors, check the auto-sync box:

[image]

After that, any time you click on a database in the right-hand navigator, it will automatically be set as the active database, so things should just work.

These types of pain points are enough to drive you away from new tools, this one in particular.  Hang in there!