# DBeaver can only see default PostgreSQL database in connection

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

I use DBeaver v 5.2.5 on Windows and use it to connect to PostgreSQL databases.

To create a connection, I must specify the database and I have no mean to see other databases on the same server.

A colleague using DBeaver 5.3 on Mac has an option to see all databases, not just the default one.

Is there an equivalent setup on the windows version?

Answer (score 482, accepted):

On the connection, right-click -> `Edit connection` -> `Connection settings` -> on the tabbed panel, select `PostgreSQL`, check the box `Show all databases`.

**UPDATE 19.02.2024**

Checkbox is moved to `Main` Tab. So flow is:

On the connection, right-click -> Edit connection -> Connection settings -> check the box `Show all databases`.

Comment: how is this not a default? why yes, i would like to manage databases in an app made for managing databases.

Comment: this causes a connection reset / lost connection. What setting do I need to fix on my cluster? without `show all databases`  connection works fine.  @northamerican `show all databases` can cause dropped connections aparently.

Comment: @northamerican yep, totally don't get it.

Comment: This should be the default behaviour. Thanks Benny.

Comment: How is this not set by default

Comment: Additionally, I have to specify e.g. "postgres" as the connection's database name, otherwise it is using the user as the database name, which will result in an error when connecting.

Answer (score 76):

### 2023 Update...

1. Right-click on your connection
2. Click "Edit connection"
3. Left panel, click "Connection settings"
4. Select PostgreSQL tab Check the box "Show all databases"

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you, this saved me hours. I can't believe this isn't the default behavior, their UI can be incredibly confusing sometimes.

Comment: these are the same steps as the top answer... what's the 2023 update?

Comment: Note: Same thing was happening to me, and it was already selected, I've deselected and selected again, clicked ok, and tables appeared.

Comment: Thank you, had this same setting on the Oracle DB

Answer (score 16):

## 2024 solution

They moved it from tab **PostgreSQL** to tab **Main**.

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Thank you. This is so strange feature existing in there.

Comment: Thank you.  You saved an additional 20 minutes not being able to find a TRULY DUMB option not to have on by default.

Answer (score 5):

The same problem in DBeaver 21.3.1, PostgreSQL 14.1 installed with `brew` on macOS Catalina. I've solved it in the Connection settings:

> On the connection, right-click -> Edit connection -> Connection settings -> then click button "Driver Settings", check "Embedded" checkbox.

Comment: I had to close and re-open dbeaver to make this to work, but works now!

Comment: I had "Show All Databases" checked and still couldn't see all of my databases. This answer got me there.

Answer (score 1):

Today I had to reinstall DBeaver on a new machine and this time, I let DBeaver download the postgresql drivers.

In this case, I can see the other databases so I can only assume that it was due to the jdbc drivers I loaded

Answer (score 0):

After creating a database within DBeaver V23.3.3 by restoring it from a backup (which came from another machine), it would only show up if I also checked the 'Show Template Databases'.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone have trouble seeing all the database although you have checked the "Show all databases", check if you're using the "Host" or "URL".
Selecting "URL" won't show all the database
[image]

Answer (score 0):

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gpCQC.png)

1.Click edit connection
2. Click PostgreSQL
3. Click show all databases