# Dbeaver: can't find database in navigator

Tags: dbeaver

I executed

```
select * from pg_database
```

and I think the results, see screenprint below, mean that there should be a database called "President".

However, I can't find this database in the navigator (leftside in screenprint) and can't query from it.

Some time ago the database "President" was visible in the navigator, just like the database "someOtherDataBase", but now it seems to be gone!

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DBeaver can only see default PostgreSQL database in connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235029/dbeaver-can-only-see-default-postgresql-database-in-connection)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Found it! I needed to switch on "Show all databases".

[image]

Comment: Took me nearly an hour to find this configuration prompt.

You can find it at;

Windows - Preferences - Connections - Drivers - PostgreSQL - "Show all database"

Answer (score 1):

Click on the Windows tab that is available on the toolbar and there we will see the option for the Database Navigator

[image: How to get Database Navigator in DBeaver in mac]