# How can I configure DBeaver to show my schema?

Tags: java, postgresql, dbeaver

I am trying to use PostgreSQL in a Spring Boot application. I am using Liquibase for the db versioning. I can see, that the database does store my data, but when I connect with DBeaver, I do not see the schema. I can't load and save to this DB. Does somebody know how to show my PostgreSQL DB in DBeaver? I never faced this issue before.

When I am browsing the database in DBeaver, there are no schemas, but in the pg admin there are some. Unfortunately pg admin is not very usable.

Comment: Is it due to the single database thing in DBeaver?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235029/dbeaver-can-only-see-default-postgresql-database-in-connection

Comment: @mdh databases != schemas

Comment: @MarkRotteveel just wanted to make sure the database with the desired schema is visible for him.

Comment: Do you use the same URL and credentials in DBeaver as you do in the app?

Comment: Thanks mdh. Crazy shid. How should a normal user ever know this? I am happy when i can retire.

Comment: haha no worries, this is quite a trap.

Comment: There are different reasons for the lack of objects in the navigation tree. First, please check the "Connection view" settings. Right-click on the connection Database Navigator tree, then choose "Connection view" and one of the modes. My advice is to use Advanced mode. If your schema is system schema and you are in Simple mode - then no system schemas in the tree. Another reason can be - object filters. You can find them in the "Connection settings" -> General -> Filters -> Schemas/Users. Maybe some schema names were added there.

Comment: @LonWo Thanks for this comment, SYSTEM schema was not in the list and it appeared  after switching Connection view to advanced