# DBeaver does not see tables in databases other than the default database - PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, dbeaver

> DBeaver 22.2.5
> PostgreSQL 16

DBeaver does not see tables in databases other than the *default* database, and also sees tables from the default database in all non-databases. If I switch to a non-default database and create a table, the table will be created in the default database, but will be showed in all databases the same if delete. Role - superuser.

pgAdmin works correctly.
What, how?

I'm just starting to use the instrument and would appreciate all the detailed and banal instructions.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> (set as default) - does not help.
- Filters disabled
- SQL Editor -> Open SQL console - does not help.

Comment: This seems extraordinarily unlikely.  Most likely you are misunderstanding something about the UI, and aren't really connected to the database you think you are connected to.  Can you only reproduce this behavior on those specific versions?  Why are you using a non-current version of DBeaver?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [DBeaver can only see default PostgreSQL database in connection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54235029/dbeaver-can-only-see-default-postgresql-database-in-connection)

Answer (score 7):

Right click on your connection. Select edit connection --> connection settings, select PostgreSQL tab, check "show all databases"

I had the same issue and i solved it this way.

Best regards.

Comment: Yes finallly figured it out! Thanks