Flutter serverpod issues with sample project Mac, database seems to be missing tables
Mac M1, Serverpod 2.0.1,
Flutter 3.22.2 • channel stable • https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
Framework • revision 761747bfc5 (5 weeks ago) • 2024-06-05 22:15:13 +0200
Engine • revision edd8546116
Tools • Dart 3.4.3 • DevTools 2.34.3
I am trying to get the email auth to work.
I am following the article here: here
Everything went fine, I could create my migrations and apply them
Internal server error. Failed to connect to database in future call manager.
DatabaseException: relation "serverpod_future_call" does not exist

Starting the server I get:
Internal server error. Failed to connect to database in future call manager.
DatabaseException: relation "serverpod_future_call" does not exist

Connecting to the running DB it looks like there are no tables:

As far as I can tell, manually creating the tables should only be needed on Windows but I am on a Mac...
I searched and found this:
SO
But it is supposed to be Windows only...

Not sure what happened, I restarted the server and now it seems to work...

This answer let me know why I couldn't see the tables...
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77200000/dbeaver-does-not-see-tables-in-databases-other-than-the-default-database-postg

This error means that you have not applied the migration (or the migration failed).
Internal server error. Failed to connect to database in future call manager.
DatabaseException: relation "serverpod_future_call" does not exist

It is a little obscure message but it means that the table serverpod_future_call was not found. The first query Serverpod made was targeting this table but it did not exist.
As an FYI, the migration system works for Windows too, no need to manually apply anything.
