Dbeaver not see database PostgreSQL
I use postgreSQL with DBeaver, and I have a problem: when I create a database, add tables and data to it, make select queries, everything goes well, but when I save the script and close the application, then the next time I open it I see only the default postgres database and the script that I saved last time. At the same time, if I try to create a database with the name that I had last time, it says that it already exists. That is, the database exists, but I do not see it. What should I do to solve this?

The connection object in the database navigator has a database name in it. You must create a second connection object (copy the first), and put the name of the new database into it. Or check the "Show all databases" checkbox near the database name field. Let me know if that helps, so I can make it an answer.
See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77200000/dbeaver-does-not-see-tables-in-databases-other-than-the-default-database-postg

@hobgoblin thanks a lot, it seems like the answer to the question you’ve sent via link can solve my problem. Where’s “show all databases” checkbox? I would like to know this too. There’re a lot of control panels near the database name of field so I can’t find it. Thanks for help

Right click on the connection, "Edit Connection", on the "Main" tab, about the 4 line, there is a field called "Database:", and to the right is a check box "Show all databases".
